# How to install dpkg file on debian linux?

Tags: linux

I am new to Linux and I want to install .Deb software package in Linux. Let say I want to install chromex64.deb, how to install it? can anyone explain it?

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i chromex64.deb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install by using `dpkg -i` command.
Navigate to download directory and open the terminal.
Run the following code:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

If there is more deb file, specify the file name in place of *
If you find missing dependencies, you can try
`sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`

Answer (score 2):

You could try running `dpkg -i chromex64.deb`

If an error occurs saying that some dependencies are missing, install them using `apt-get install`